# Newline character written to file with echo works in shell, but literal in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ubuntu, posix

I'm on a **Ubuntu 20.04** system, and I'm using **Python 3.8** to write a script that does multiple things using configurable lines of bash, but one of them is that it creates desktop shortcuts.

This single-line command creates a desktop shortcut, **and works flawlessly when I execute it directly in my terminal**:

```
echo "[Desktop Entry]"$'\n'"Type=Application"$'\n'"Name[en_US]=Documents"$'\n'"Exec=pcmanfm ~/Documents"$'\n'"Icon=system-file-manager" > ~/Desktop/1;
```

However, when I execute it in Python, like so:

`foobar.py`

```
rl = """echo "[Desktop Entry]"$'\n'"Type=Application"$'\n'"Name[en_US]=Documents"$'\n'"Exec=pcmanfm ~/Documents"$'\n'"Icon=system-file-manager" > ~/Desktop/1;"""
subprocess.run(rl, shell=True)
```

...instead of creating a desktop shortcut with the proper name, icon, and action, **it creates an empty file that contains the following text**:

`0.txt`:

```
[Desktop Entry]$\nType=Application$\nName[en_US]=Sign Out$\nExec=/home/agent/QaSC/login/login.bin$\nIcon=system-switch-user
```

Is there any particular reason why Python would be handling the newline characters differently than the bash shell does, and if so, how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `$'\n'` is a `bash` extension, but `subprocess.run()` uses `sh` by default.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with shell syntax? You can just put a literal newline in the string with Python.

Comment: Writing to a file in python is very easy without using `subprocess` and a shell.

Comment: @Barmar the code above is a simplification - I'm not storing the command directly in a string. I only formatted it like this so the question could be more easily answered

Comment: When I try it, the output file has unwanted `$` symbols in it, but it also correctly line breaks and does not contain `\n` sequences. Mint 20.03, Python 3.8.10 so quite similar to your system.

Answer (score 1):

`$'...'` is a `bash` extension, but the default shell used when `shell=True` is specified is `sh`. Use the `executable` option to specify an alternate shell.

```
subprocess.run(rl, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the argument to `echo` has quotes, it could contain literal newlines at the command line, and therefore also in the Python process. I see no reason to use the Bash extension `$'\n'` syntax.

```
$ echo "foo
> bar"
foo
bar
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run('echo "foo\nbar"', shell=True)
foo
bar
CompletedProcess(args='echo "foo\nbar"', returncode=0)
>>>
```

(It's also unclear why the Python code doesn't just write a file in the normal way, but I assume the command in the OP is essentially a placeholder.)